# Can't open Sqlite database in read-only mode

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mono, xamarin.ios

I have a Sqlite database that I include with my MonoTouch app. It has worked fine for me so far, but now I want to open it in read-only mode rather than read-write.

So I have changed the connection string to include 'Read Only=True', but when I call Open(), I get the following error:

```
Library used incorrectly (at Mono.Data.Sqlite3.Open)
```

If I dig into the exception it shows

```
_errorCode = Misuse
```

and that's about all the info it gives.

Here's the code:

```
var _conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=db/sampleDb;Read Only=True");
_conn.Open ();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You found a bug in `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll`.

The `Create` flag is appended (by default) before the `ReadOnly` flag is parsed and set. The resulting flag is invalid and **sqlite** reports an error.

I will fix this for future releases (of Mono and MonoTouch...). If this blocks you then please open a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and I'll attach a fixed assembly (with instructions to replace the existing one) to the bug report.

Comment: Very useful to know, thanks a lot. I'm not exactly blocked by it but I would like to open a bug to track the status - will do so now.

Comment: In case this is of use to people, here is a link to the bug I raised: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2721

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (aspnet core):

```
var _conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=db/sampleDb;mode=ReadOnly");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?:

```
var _conn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=db/sampleDb;mode=ro");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, I just tried it (not using MonoTouch) and it worked for me.

Do you have the latest version of `System.Data.SQLite.dll`?
If yes, then maybe it's a problem related to MonoTouch.